# CSS DIV Swap without fixed height?

Tags: html, css

I am curious if it is possible to achieve a simple div swap using only css if the div does not have a fixed height.  I have searched far and wide for an answer and have come up with little solid discussion on the matter.

The idea is to have an expansive beer list divided into four separate divs and to display only one of them at a time.  When clicking a corresponding anchor, the div displayed would switch while hiding the other three.  The first div should display when the page loads. I have a little experience with this and have had success but only with fixed sizes as the foremost div would hide all other divs behind it.

These particular divs will contain formatted tables and unordered-lists. I am not sure if that will have any affect, but thought it was worth mentioning just in case.  The divs cannot have a fixed height because the number of items in each will vary.  I haven't yet coded it as I am not sure if it is worth the time investment but the HTML would look something like this:

```
<div id="secondaryNav">      
  <ul>
    <li>Link to div1</li>
    <li>Link to div2</li>
    <li>Link to div3</li>
    <li>Link to div4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="swappedContent">
  <div id="1">
    <table>
      <tr>content</tr> x 40-50
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="2">
    <table>
      <tr>content</tr> x 40-50
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="3">
    <table>
      <tr>content</tr> x 40-50
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="4">
    <table>
      <tr>content</tr> x 40-50
    </table>
  </div>
</div><!--swappedContent-->
```

I found an example that I am modeling this layout after (that uses javascript) but I am not sure of the appropriateness of linking to a site which I do not own here.  If I should link to it for clarity, please let me know.

Comment: i think you need javascript.  css is for styling, not controlling click events.  i'd like to see how someone would be able to do this with just css.

Comment: You are probably right, will most likely end up with using a simple script, but am just curious if it is possible.

Comment: I do not think it is possible with just CSS. HTML describes text, CSS describes how it looks, and JavaScript handles user actions (clicking etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using the CSS "display". In each div do:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">
```

And then when you want to display the div, do the following in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
```

So in the end, you'd have something like:

```
<div id="secondaryNav">      
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showDiv('1')">Link to div1</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showDiv('2')">Link to div2</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showDiv('3')">Link to div3</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showDiv('4')">Link to div4</a>
</div>

<div id="swappedContent">
  <div id="1">
    <table>
      <tr>content</tr> x 40-50
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="2" style="display:none;">
    <table>
      <tr>content</tr> x 40-50
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="3" style="display:none;">
    <table>
      <tr>content</tr> x 40-50
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="4" style="display:none;">
    <table>
      <tr>content</tr> x 40-50
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(divId) {
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        document.getElementById(i).style.display = "none";
    }

    document.getElementById(divId).style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Note: be sure to put the script in an appropriate place (usually in the  element).

Comment: Seems like a simple enough script, but I am curious if it can be done using only CSS.

Comment: See my comment on your question. I do not think it is possible. CSS just says how things look. Not when they look one way or another. JavaScript handles actions, including rearranging the page when a user clicks something.

Comment: If you want a dumb analogy. CSS is like hair ribbons. They let you style your hair. However, the ribbons cannot change themselves. You need to change them. Decoration vs. action.

Comment: Definitely check out http://w3schools.com/ (it is like the authority on this stuff)

Comment: Once a page loads, HTML and CSS are done. JavaScript can change them, etc. But once it on the page, it's static. JavaScript is the world of action!